# Mapping Multiple Lists in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: list, sorting, dart, element, flutter

I have SWIFT code where I've mapped a set of lists with equal number of elements where 1 was a list of ints and they were mapped in descending order.  Here is my SWIFT Code...

```
class Video
{
    let videoID: String
    let rank: Int
    let title: String
    let imageString: String

    init(videoID: String, rank: Int, title: String, imageString: String)
    {
        self.videoID = videoID
        self.rank = rank
        self.title = title
        self.imageString = imageString
    }
}

var videos = [Video]()

videos.sort { $0.rank < $1.rank }

self.vidTitleArray = videos.map { $0.title }
self.vidRankArray = videos.map { $0.rank }
self.vidIdArray = videos.map { $0.videoID }
self.vidImageArray = videos.map { $0.imageString }
```

Here is where I am in Flutter, but I'm getting errors going forward...

```
class videos{
  String videoId;
  int rank;
  String title;
  String imageString;

  videos(this.videoId, this.rank, this.title, this.imageString);
}
```

How do I make a `list` from the class constructor then rearrange all elements in descending order mapped to rank?

***** OPTION *****

Here is my code without using a `Video` class.  I got it to rank correctly using a `SplayTreeMap` but if `Value` is ever the same it only brings back 1 node.  Is there a way to map all 4 maps descending with `Value`?

Map myMap = event.data.snapshot.value; //store each map

```
                          var titles = myMap.values;

                          List onesTitles = new List();
                          List onesIds = new List();
                          List onesImages = new List();
                          List onesRank = new List();

                          for (var items in titles) {
                            onesTitles.add(items['vidTitle']);
                            onesIds.add(items['vidId']);
                            onesImages.add(items['vidImage']);
                            onesRank.add(items['Value']);
                          }

                          names = onesTitles;
                          ids = onesIds;
                          numbers = onesRank;
                          vidImages = onesImages;
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it more clear on how to use List.sort().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.sort()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-core/List/sort.html) for that purpose, I have created a custom example where I hard coded 3 instances of your `Videos` class, and then added them in my build method in a `List` in ascending order. Using `List.sort()` and `compareTo`, I was able to rearrange them in an descending order.

```
List<Videos> myList = [_firstVideos, _secondVideos, _thirdVideos];
sort() {
      for (var video in myList) {
        print(video.rank); ///prints 1 2 3 
      }
      myList.sort((y, x) => x.rank.compareTo(y.rank));

      for (var video in myList) {
        print(video.rank);  ///prints 3 2 1
      }
    }
```

...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


    void main(){
      runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(),));
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

      Videos _firstVideos = new Videos(
        videoId: "0001",
        rank: 1,
        title: "My First Video",
        imageString: "My First Image",
      );
      Videos _secondVideos = new Videos(
        videoId: "0002",
        rank: 2,
        title: "My Seocnd Video",
        imageString: "My Second Image",
      );

      Videos _thirdVideos = new Videos(
        videoId: "0003",
        rank: 3,
        title: "My Third Video",
        imageString: "My Third Image",
      );

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Videos> myList = [_firstVideos,_secondVideos,_thirdVideos];
        sort()
        {
          myList.sort((y,x)=>x.rank.compareTo(y.rank));

        print(myList[0].title);
        }
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Center(
            child: new FlatButton(onPressed: sort, child: new Text("Sort")),
          ),
        );
      }
    }


    class Videos{
      String videoId;
      int rank;
      String title;
      String imageString;

      Videos({this.videoId, this.rank, this.title, this.imageString});
    }
```

Comment: @azia Please look at my other `OPTION` I've added.  I'm trying to sort without building `Video` lists